# Java. Проблема с чтением и записью примитивов в потоках

Tags: java

При попытках чтения или записи примитивных данных в файле с помощью DataInputStream и DataOutputStream происходит невероятная чертовщина. Судя по примерам в интернетах всё делается правильно, однако программа выдаёт совершенно неожиданные результаты.

Например, при чтении из файла с содержимым:

> 1 15 6 7

```
DataInputStream FileRead = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("M") );
System.out.println(FileRead.readInt() );
FileRead.close();
```

-- вывод такой: 824193333.

Понятно, что я ожидал такой: 1.

Идём дальше.

Для записи делается следующее:

```
DataOutputStream FileRead = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("F") );
FileRead.writeInt(300);
FileRead.close();
```

В результате содержимым файла становится: ,.

А надо, очевидно: 300.

Прошу объяснить, что я делаю не так и чего я, возможно, недопонял.

Comment: `readInt -- Reads four input bytes and returns an int value.` [источник](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt())

Comment: Дело в том, что `DataXXXStream` записывают и читают данные не в текстовом виде, а в сериализованном. Т.е. (почти) так, как они лежат в памяти. Например, для `int` в файл будут записаны 4 байта (плюс какая-то служебная информация), которые в текстовом редакторе бедет выглядеть совсем не как число.

Comment: Вот как? Теперь понятно. А есть ли возможность читать и записывать примитивы в текстовом файле так, как это можно делать в Си?

Comment: `824193333` это `00110001001000000011000100110101`, разбиваем по 4 байта: '00110001', '00100000', '00110001', '00110101'. Далее приводим каждый в 10-ную систему: 49, 32, 49, 53. А это коды символов: '1', ' ', '1', '5'. Это почему вы такое получили :) А теперь насчет самой задачи. Пробовали через `Scanner` работать?

Comment: А насчет записи, попробуйте вместо `writeInt` написать `writeUTF(String.valueOf(300))`

Comment: Нет, но прямо сейчас попробую.

Comment: `Scanner` для чтения, `PrintWriter` для записи. Как вариант. Не забудьте, что считывать будете строки, которые нужно парсить в числа.